# My program doesn't deal cards correctly after the first round

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a program that has to go until one of the players get 30 points, if I play it only 1 round it works perfectly but when I try to deal the cards again (different cards per round) it deals the last card it gave the round before and the other 2 are the same (sometimes it doesn't even deal them).

```
   while (Player1Point != 30 && Player2Point != 30){
    for (int i = CardCount; i < Count; i++){
        DealCard(Deck, i, &Hand1, &Hand2, Count, j);
        j++;
    }
    Count = Count + 4;
    CardCount = CardCount + 4;
```

Here's the function DealCard:

```
void DealCard(int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS], int i, int Hand1[NUMBER][SUITS], int Hand2[NUMBER][SUITS], int Count, int j){
if (i < Count && j < 3){
    Hand1[j][0] = Deck[i][0];
    Hand1[j][1] = Deck[i][1];
    Hand2[j][0] = Deck[i+3][0];
    Hand2[j][1] = Deck[i+3][1];
}
```

}

The arrays I use for the cards:

```
char* suit[SUITS] = {"Espada", "Oro", "Copa", "Basto"};
char* num[NUMBER] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "diez", "once", "doce"};
```

When i try to deal for the second time it gives me the last card and 2 "uno de Espada" or 2 "uno de (null)"

EDIT:
The MRE (still 66 lines)

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SUITS 4
#define NUMBER 10
#define CARDS 40
#define PLAYERS 3
char* suit[SUITS] = {"Espada", "Oro", "Copa", "Basto"};
char* num[NUMBER] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "diez", "once", "doce"};
int main(){
    int Player2Point = 0, Player1Point = 0, CardCount = 0, j = 0, Count = 3;
    int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS];
    int Hand1[NUMBER][SUITS];
    int Hand2[NUMBER][SUITS];
    srand(time(0));
    InitDeck(Deck);
    ShuffleDeck(Deck);
    while (Player1Point != 30 && Player2Point != 30){
        for (int i = CardCount; i < Count; i++){
            DealCard(Deck, i, &Hand1, &Hand2, Count, j);
            j++;
        }
        PrintCard(Hand1, 3);
        Count = Count + 4;
        CardCount = CardCount + 4;
        Player1Point++;
    }
    return 0;
}
void InitDeck(int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS]){
    int suit, num, row;
    row = 0;
    for (suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
        for (num = 0; num < 10; num++){
            Deck[row][0] = suit;
            Deck[row][1] = num;
            row++;
        }
    }
}
void ShuffleDeck(int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS]){
    int Src, Dest, i;
    for(i = 0; i < CARDS; i++){
        Src = i;
        Dest = rand()%CARDS;
        SwapCards(Deck, i, Dest);
    }
}
void SwapCards(int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS], int Src, int Dest){
    int Temp;
    Temp = Deck[Dest][0];
    Deck[Dest][0] = Deck[Src][0];
    Deck[Src][0] = Temp;
    Temp = Deck[Dest][1];
    Deck[Dest][1] = Deck[Src][1];
    Deck[Src][1] = Temp;
}
void DealCard(int Deck[CARDS][PLAYERS], int i, int Hand1[NUMBER][SUITS], int Hand2[NUMBER][SUITS], int Count, int j){
    if (i < Count && j < 3){
        Hand1[j][0] = Deck[i][0];
        Hand1[j][1] = Deck[i][1];
        Hand2[j][0] = Deck[i+3][0];
        Hand2[j][1] = Deck[i+3][1];
    }
}
void PrintCard(int Hand1[NUMBER][SUITS], int size){
    printf("Your cards: \n");
    int psuit, pnum;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        psuit = Hand1[i][0];
        pnum = Hand1[i][1];
        printf("Card: %s de %s\n", num[pnum], suit[psuit]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to reset all the variables for the next game? Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm suppose to give different cards every round, but I'll post the Minimal Reproducible Example now.

Comment: your cards doesn't have to be randomly dealed? just different from the previous round?

Comment: `DealCard([...], &Hand1, &Hand2, [...]);` -> `void DealCard([...], int Hand1[NUMBER][SUITS], int Hand2[NUMBER][SUITS], [...])`. sure that's right? Please check your [mcve] before you post... it doesn't compile. Missing a library and order and arguments mismatch

Comment: @JHBonarius It compiled here, I tried on onlinegdb and it compiles.

Comment: I can compile it without problem

Comment: OK, it compiles, but it's not 'really' correct. [Check the warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/jfYMer)

Comment: MS VC gives 6 warnings and 5 errors so it won't compile. Mostly due to the missing prototypes for 5 functions.

Comment: I'm quite lost, but thanks anyways